# jQuery load with variable, and split into 2 parts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-load

I'm looking for a way of increasing the performance of my code. Currently I do something similar to this:

```
$(".div1").load("Page.aspx #section1");
$(".div2").load("Page.aspx #section2");
```

However, this means I'm having to make 2 `GET` requests. Is there any way of reducing this to 1 request by doing something like this:

```
var content = $.load("Page.aspx");
$(".div1").html(content("#section1"));
$(".div2").html(content("#section2"));
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.get('Page.aspx', function(data) {
  var dom = $(data);
  $(".div1").html(dom.find("#section1"));
  $(".div2").html(dom.find("#section2"));
});
```

btw: probably you'll need a holder-element around your sections, because `dom` in my example holds the first leve of your `<body>` tag content and `find` won't find anything on this first level:

```
<body>
  <div id="holder">
    <div id="section1"></div>
    <div id="section2></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: hmm its just returning blank :S

Comment: I added an usecase example to the answer, have a look wether this works

Answer (score 0):

Can you switch to use JSON?

```
$.getJSON('Page.aspx', function(data) {
    $(".div1").html(data.section1);
    $(".div2").html(data.section2);
});
```

This would be faster than doing a regular get and traversing the result, albeit you'll need to encode your response from the server.